# jumpy touchpad in ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS with ThinkPad T15g-Gen-2i

Tags: 20.04, touchpad, thinkpad

I have been using Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS on my ThinkPad T15g-Gen-2i since the past week, and the trackpad has become jumpy.

External mouse works perfectly fine, but the trackpad doesn't.

The settings are

```
Touchpad : on
Natural Scrolling : on
Touchpad speed : right in the middle of the bar
Tap to Click : on
Two finger scrolling : on
Edge scrolling : off


$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal
```

Any suggestions on resolving this would help. The laptop is in warranty so if it's a hardware issue, I can defintiely take it to the manufacturer, but considering that this was working for the last 4 days, it probably is a configuration tweak.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Same here with an X1 Extreme G4, also since a week or two.